# Bleeding brakes on a 06 chevy equinox

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, bleeding, equinox

I changed the master cylinder and front calipers. I also bled all the lines but when I start the car the brakes still goto the floor. Should I bleed them with engine running?

When I did this the car sometimes dies on me.

Comment: Did you bench bleed the master before you put it on the vehicle?

Comment: I am just going to throw out this tidbit that you might want to make sure that all the vacuum lines are present and not rotted etc.

Comment: You have a vacuum leak. Not having bled the brakes correctly (bench bleeding the master, etc.) will cause braking problems, but should not cause the engine to die. It's likely that the vacuum connection to the new master is not sealing correctly.

Comment: You may need a tool to cycle the ABS pump if you installed a master cylinder full of air. Some scan tools can do this. You could also try a pressure bleeder (these are really nice to have in general and makes the bleeding job much faster).

Answer (score 0):

bleed the four tires when the engine is running,If the problem continues them you know that you master cylinder  has problem.

Comment: while a bad part is a possibility it's more likely OP didn't follow service info and either didn't bleed the master, doesn't have a scantool to pulse the bypass modulator valve or didn't completely bleed the system.